# Get Facebook fan count of age restricted page

Tags: facebook

I need to get the Facebook fan_count, part of the data returned by the main open graph API call for a page, for an age restricted Facebook page.  Anyone know how to do this?  For instance: http://graph.facebook.com/BudLight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to provide `access_token` (see ["Authentication"](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)).

Comment: Trying "Authenticating As An Application" doesn't work.  And in my app, users don't authenticate themselves, so I don't have one of their access tokens.  The app will be installed as a tab on a Page profile.  I wish there was someway that it was the page with authenticated.  It's the pages own fan count that I want to retrieve.

Comment: @weotch Maybe FQL would work then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231099/how-does-one-retrieve-the-fan-count-for-a-facebook-application-page-using-the-gra/3231744#3231744 . If that doesn't work either then as a last resort you can authenticate yourself with offline_access permission once and then use that non-expiring access token to retrieve data.

Comment: FQL didn't work but your last resort option does.  Not sure how long I get to keep offline access, but I think it'll work.  One thing I was considering is if the manage_pages permission would give me a permanent access token or if it would be destroyed when I lose my main token.

Comment: @weotch manage_pages is permanent just like offline_access so they shouldn't expire (anytime soon at least, not sure if there is time limit). manage_pages is something similar to authenticating as an app, only this one authenticates you as a user created page (if you created any). If app token doesn't let you query the table then I doubt page token would (but you can try if you want, who knows).

Answer (score 0):

fan_count isn't restricted, and there's no need to provide an access_token.

You just need to query graph by page_id, for example, for BudLight:
http://graph.facebook.com/110515375643035

Comment: That isn't the actual company page for Bud Light.  That is the generated page created by likes.  The page id of the real page (http://www.facebook.com/BudLight) is 54876245094.  Which is restricted (http://graph.facebook.com/54876245094).

Comment: misleading answer. you need an access token for age restricted pages to get the fan_count